# jsHint "function not defined" issue, order of function declarations matters?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

Passing this code through jsHint:

```
var A = function (spec) { 
  "use strict";
  var a = function () {
    return b();
  };

  var b = function () {
    return 5;
  };

  a();
};
```

returns this error:

```
Line 4: return b();
'b' is not defined.
```

I understand this might have to do with "hoisting" as explained here: [JavaScript function order: why does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609276/javascript-function-order-why-does-it-matter)

However, the following code returns the same error:

```
var A = function (spec) { 
  "use strict";
  function a () {
    return b();
  }

  function b () {
    return 5;
  }

  a();
};
```

If I understand correctly, at least the second code snippet should not return an error. Am I mistaken?

Even considering the hoisting mechanism, I still do not understand why the first code snippet should be wrong. Function `a` is only called after function `b` is defined, so `b` would be in `a`'s closure. Is my code wrong or is jsHint wrong?

I understand that this question is purely academic, because the code works as expected in all browser. Nevertheless, I'd like to know why jsHint throws an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a false positive in jsLint.
Both of your code snippets work fine.

Ignore the warning.

Comment: I don't know why jsLint (and its fork) ignores function statement hoisting.

Comment: I thought that this is covered by several issues in their github: [61](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/61), [47](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/47), [29](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/29). [29](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/29) is closed in March 2011 with comment that the issue is fixed (in their master branch anyways).

Answer (score 2):

The first example is a hoisting problem because a() references b() before it's declared. The solution is to have 'var a, b;' after your "use strict"; statement.

Answer (score 0):

jsHint is trying to help you by pointing out potential problems and non-conventional code.

In this case, it's not happy because it might be difficult for a human to understand -- even though it's perfectly valid Javascript.