# JavaScript Internals 101: Hoisting variables and functions

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Consider the following examples:

```
var company = 'Apple',
    log = console.log;

function f1() {
    log(company);
    var company = 'Twilio';
    log(company)
}

function f2() {
    log(company());

    function company() {
        return 'Zynga';
    }
}

function f3() {
    log(company());
    var company = function() { return 'RIM'; };
}

log(company);
log('---');
f1();
log('---');   
f2();
log('---');
f3();
```

The output from firebug is:

```
"Apple"
---
undefined
"Twilio"
---
"Zynga"
---
TypeError: company is not a function
```

So why is hoisting in `f3` giving me the error while others are working just fine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609276/javascript-function-order-why-does-it-matter/7610883#7610883

Comment: This blog post covers it super good: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rewrite your `f3` function to show what it would look like after variable hoisting:

```
function f3() {
    log(company());
    var company = function() { return 'RIM'; };
}
```

becomes:

```
function f3() {
    var company; // declaration hoisted

    log(company());
    company = function() { return 'RIM'; };
}
```

Now you can see that you are attempting to execute an undefined variable, not a function (hence the "not a function" error).

Note that this is difference from the output of `f2` because function declarations are hoisted as a unit.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is hoisted, but setting it is not.

The value of `company` in `f3` is not set until after `log(company())` is called.  You can see the same behavior in `f1`.