# javascript returns undefind for a globally declared variable

Tags: javascript

I am a beginer to javascript.I have a doubt.my code is given bellow.when i run this the 1st alert box displaying "undefind".i can not understand why?thanks alot..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 123;
   function foo()
   {
     alert(a);
     var a = 890;
     alert(a);
   }
     foo();
     alert(a); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ExplosionPills Really? http://jsfiddle.net/Tph8g/

Comment: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Comment: Shameless plug: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7609276/617762

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because after *hoisting* but *before execution*, your `foo()` function internally looks like:

```
function foo() {
    var a; // declaration hoisted to top
    alert(a); // the local var is 'undefined' at this point
    a = 890; // assignment operation not hoisted
    alert(a);
}
```

Read more about hoisting here:

- http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting
- http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/

Comment: yep this is a good way to learn more: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/

Comment: thanks alot for the links..now i got an idea..thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because of variable declaration hoisting. Variable declarations are hoisted to the top of its scope. So that means, technically, your code is executed like this:

```
var a;
a = 123;
function foo()
{
  var a;
  alert(a);
  a = 890;
  alert(a);
}
foo();
alert(a);
```

In this scenario, `a` is first defined globally, with an `undefined` value. Then, its value is set to `123`. When the function is called, a new `a` is declared immediately in the function with an `undefined` value as a local variable, and that's why `undefined` is alerted at first. Then, you set its value to `890`. So even though you use `var` in the middle of the function, it doesn't mean that's how it's executed, because of hoisting.

Comment: thanks alot..now i understand what is happening inside.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the variable a twice which gives the weird result. As now it is scoped twice differently.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 123;
   function foo()
   {
     alert(a);
     a = 890;
     alert(a);
   }
     foo();
     alert(a); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is wrong?

Comment: Can you explain why this is correct? There's no real explanation of the problem, no real explanation of your code, and code that doesn't relate to the original. The original code redeclares the `a` variable in the function, so there's no reason for you to assume it should be a global variable throughout the whole code. I'm sure the OP has a reason for redeclaring `a` locally, and there's nothing wrong with that. The point is the confusion that ensues with variable hoisting.