# ReferenceError: function is not defined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I try to load this script in Firefox, it gives me this error: 
Reference Error: onListFriends is not defined.

The code works fine in Safari and Chrome.

```
listFriends(onListFriends);

function onListFriends() {
    console.log("friends were listed.");
    setOnline();
}
```

And here is the listFriends function defined later in the file:

```
function listFriends(callback) {
    FB.api(
        "me/friends",

    function (response) {
        console.log("Got FB.api response");
        var numOnline = 0;
        var numFriends = response.data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < numFriends; i++) {
            isOnline(i, response.data, gotOnline);
            var callbackInc = 0;

            function callbackIfYouCan(callback) {
                callbackInc++;
                if (callbackInc == numFriends) {
                    interiorCallback(callback);
                }
            }

            function gotOnline(res, ind, data) {
                console.log("Got response from isOnline: " + res);
                var id = data[ind].id;
                var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                checkbox.name = "friends";
                checkbox.id = id;
                checkbox.value = data[ind].name;
                console.log("For user " + checkbox.value);
                var label = document.createElement('label');
                label.htmlFor = id;
                label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[ind].name));
                if (res == 1) {
                    document.getElementById("online").appendChild(checkbox);
                    document.getElementById("online").appendChild(label);
                    document.getElementById("online").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                    numOnline++;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("offline").appendChild(checkbox);
                    document.getElementById("offline").appendChild(label);
                    document.getElementById("offline").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                }
                callbackIfYouCan(callback);
            }
        }

        function interiorCallback(callback) {
            if (numOnline > 0) {
                var textField = document.createElement('input');
                textField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                textField.id = "message";
                textField.value = "I would like to hang out at this place in 15 minutes.";

                var button = document.createElement('button');
                button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                console.log("Created tagging button.");
                button.onclick = function () {
                    console.log("Tagging button pressed.");
                    getIdsFromCheckboxes();
                }
                button.innerHTML = "Tag your friends.";

                document.getElementById("online").appendChild(textField);
                document.getElementById("online").appendChild(button);
            }
            callback();
        }
    });

}
```

What is the difference between the way Firefox and Chrome loads this code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just these two pieces of code are not enough to cause an error: http://jsfiddle.net/qd9aexqn/ More info is necessary

Answer (score -2, accepted):

JS interpretor read script line by line. In your case, when you transmit onListFriends like a callback, interpretor doesn't know there declaration.

So ... switch your function declaration and listFriends call:

```
function onListFriends() {
    console.log("friends were listed.");
    setOnline();
}  
listFriends(onListFriends);
```

Comment: The reason this is only happening in Firefox is that Firefox isn't performing "hoisting" of variables and functions to the top of where they were defined.

Comment: You don't have any another errors ? :O

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. Any spec complicant javascript engine (Spidermonkey included) does function declaration hoisting - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7609276).

Comment: We occasionally run into this with Firefox.  We just had a problem with an if stmt that called foo() on both branches.  foo() was defined, nested, just below the 'if'.  One branch worked, the other gets ReferenceError.

Comment: I don't really understand why this was downvoted.  I had the exact same issue, moved around my function call and it worked. It does seem like Firefox handles this in an odd way.