# cannot able to access function in Keyboard class

Tags: react-native

```
export default someclass extends React.component{
this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide',keyboardhide);
}

keyboardhide(){
this.somefunc();
}
somefunc(){

if(mode=='up'){

  Animated.timing(
    this.state.animate.marginTop,
    {
      toValue:0,
      duration: 2000,

    }
  ).start();
  Animated.timing(
    this.state.animate.width,
    {
      toValue:this.screenmanipulate(100,'width'),
      duration: 2000,

    }
  ).start();

}

else {

  Animated.timing(
    this.state.animate.marginTop,
    {
      toValue:top,
      duration: 2000,

    }
  ).start();
  Animated.timing(
    this.state.animate.width,
    {
      toValue:width,
      duration: 2000,

    }
  ).start();

}    
render{
....

.....

}
```

if I keyboard is closed it throws an error that **somefunc()** is not defined, bu **console.log()** is working, I don't know where I am going wrong,

**What i expected :**
the key event will trigger the animation

**But what happened:**
Error undefined is not an object this.somefunc()

Comment: What someFunc contain?

Comment: @DevAS I have updated the code  please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to move the `someFun` before the `keyboardhide` method. the following code is what I suugest:

```
componendDidMount(){
this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide',this.keyboardhide);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove()
}

someFun = () => {
  // you code
}

keyboardhide = () => {
this.somefunc();
}
```

the arrow function is default bind this, but the method you define the way is not to bind this. you have to bind this by manual. I suggest you use an arrow function. for more about bind this, you can see this [document](https://javascript.info/bind)

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.keyboardhide.bind(this);
    }
```

the method define order in javascript is important. for that, you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610883/5705408). it explanations it well.

Comment: why the this is not working, it supposed to work right, what is the reason, Sir?

Comment: @subhashchandru, what is the error info? if no error, you first check if the `somefun` is called, if called, it may be the `somefun` content problem

Comment: no some fun is not called, I don't think it's a content problem, I also looked into typo I think its bug, what do you think sir?

Comment: @subhashchandru, I update the answer, the wrong place is in the addListener, it should be `Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this.[your function]);`

Comment: what is happening in addListener can you explain it genius!!!

Comment: @subhashchandru, your addListener is  `Keyboard.addListener( 'keyboardDidShow', keyboardhide)`, it means the second parms not hold the component method. it should be `addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.keyboardhide)`

Answer (score 2):

Can you bind the code like the following?

```
  _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    this.somefunc();
  };
```

Comment: @subhashchandru you need to bind all your functions. Then only you will get the 'this' object.