# Order of useCallback declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Does the order of useCallback function declaration matters? For example:

**Functions declared in this order:**

1. `const aboveFunction = useCallback(()=>{ logCount() },[logCount])`
2. `const logCount = useCallback(()=>{ console.log(count) },[count])`
3. `const belowFunction = useCallback(()=>{ logCount() },[logCount])`

Notice both `aboveFunction` and `belowFunction` refers to the same `logCount`.
After we call `setCount(2)` ,

`aboveFunction()` -> `logCount()` -> `count` // 0, wheres

`belowFunction()` -> `logCount()` -> `count` // 2

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-7mofy?file=/src/index.js

```
/**
  Click increment button until count is 2, then click 
  Above and Below button and check console log
 * Even though the count value is > 0, aboveIncrement console.log(count) still gives 0
 */

import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  /** Assuming all the functions below do some intensive stuffs to justify useCallback */
  const aboveFunction = useCallback(() => {
    // ...do other intensive stuff
    logCount("Above count:"); // Above count: 0
  }, [logCount]);

  const logCount = useCallback(
    (str) => {
      // ...do other intensive stuff
      console.log(str, count);
    },
    [count]
  );

  const belowFunction = useCallback(() => {
    // ...do other intensive stuff
    logCount("Below count:"); // Above count: 2
  }, [logCount]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        Click increment button until count is 2, then click Above/ Below button
        and see console log
      </h1>
      <h2>You clicked {count} times!</h2>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          flexDirection: "column"
        }}
      >
        <button style={{ margin: 10 }} onClick={aboveFunction}>
          Above Increment Function
        </button>
        <button style={{ margin: 10 }} onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
          Increment
        </button>
        <button style={{ margin: 10 }} onClick={belowFunction}>
          Below Increment Function
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

It is apparent that the order of useCallback declaration is important in order for the code to work. However, if we write it this way
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-7mofy?file=/src/index1.js

```
  let logCount;
  const aboveFunction = useCallback(() => {
    logCount("Above count:"); // Above count: 0
  }, [logCount]);

  logCount = useCallback((str) => {
      console.log(str, count);
    }, [count]
  );

  const belowFunction = useCallback(() => {
    logCount("Below count:"); // Above count: 2
  }, [logCount]);
```

`aboveFunction` still gives stale count value. Is there any rule-of-hooks that I'm missing?

Yes a fix here is to apply `eslint no-use-before-define`. But I wanna understand the reason why .. isn’t  functions get hoisted up in JavaScript and the order in which it is declared doesn’t matter?

Comment: *"Assuming all the functions below do some intensive stuffs to justify useCallback"* useCallback does not change anything about "intensive stuff". I'd say, just get rid of `useCallback()`s in that code, but I don't understand what exactly you're trying to achieve/why you put them in there in the first place

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any rule-of-hooks that I'm missing?

You are not missing `rule-of-hooks` but, you are missing [`no-use-before-define`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define) rule.

You have to use the `logCount` function above the `aboveFunction.`

In this attached image as well

[image]

you can see, it's showing a warning for function declaration.

Maybe you can add `es-lint` in your project and make sure you add this [plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) & [no-use-before-define](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define) as well so that it will show you these types of warning in vs code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But 'no-use-before-def' isn’t fool proof, as u can see the 2nd part of my question.

Comment: And isn’t functions get hoisted up in JavaScript, and the order in which they’re declared doesn’t matter? Or it does matter only when it is wrapped in useCallback?

Comment: These types of `hoisting` we should avoid. It won't help you. It won't give you any advantage, it is only there to increase your pain. 
You can check this here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29718445/7348073,  as well.
But anyways it's a good question you asked.